# Using conditional If/else statements and Mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable based on an if/else statement. Pretty much I need to run a calculation for a new variable, but the calculation is different for men vs women. 
I know how to write the code using mutate to get a new column using the calculation, but am having a hard time creating a conditional statement based on sex. Here is what I have so far:

This is just applying the calculation to men and women:

```
test2 <- mutate(test, FEV1 = 443 - (30*Age) + (23*Height))
```

This is what I would like to do (I know it's not correct)

```
test2 <- mutate(test, FEV1 = ifelse( Sex ==1, *equation1*, *equation2*))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There exist several options, but keep it simple. Add two extra columns: one holds the conditions of men, the other column for female. Next step, add a "final" result column that preserves the result based on a simple ifelse. IFELSE( Sex ==M, column_men, column_female)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem, but you are almost there. How about:

```
library("dplyr")    
df <- data.frame(sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F"))
df$test2 <- mutate(df, var = ifelse(sex == "M", runif(1), 2))
```

You could do it as well directly (without using `mutate`).

```
df$test3 <- ifelse( df$sex == "M", runif(1), 2)
```